# Android: How to retrieve file name and extension of a resource by resource ID

Tags: java, android

I have the following:

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(resourceId);
```

The problem is, that it retrieves only the file name without the extension.

For example, if I have the following res/drawable/pic.jpg, the

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(resourceId);
```

is returning the value "pic". The extension .jpg is missing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To get "res/drawable/pic.jpg" you could use this:

```
    TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    getResources().getValue(resourceId, value, true);
    // check value.string if not null - it is not null for drawables...

    Log.d(TAG, "Resource filename:" + value.string.toString());
    // ^^ This would print res/drawable/pic.jpg
```

Source: android/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java

Comment: Indeed, and it is there from API level 1 :) Marking as the solution

Comment: Doesn't work, returns myimage.xml for me even though the real extension is png.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so

```
    Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
    for (int count = 0; count < fields.length; count++) {

        // Use that if you just need the file name
        String filename = fields[count].getName();
        Log.i("filename", filename);
        int rawId = getResources().getIdentifier(filename, "raw", getPackageName());
        TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
        getResources().getValue(rawId, value, true);
        String[] s = value.string.toString().split("/");
        Log.i("filename", s[s.length - 1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't.

Another way to do this, would be to put your graphics inside the assets folder.
Then you can access the Files directly, without your App needing any permission.

You can, for example, do so in your Activity:

```
AssetManager am = this.getApplicationContext().getAssets()
InputStream is = am.open(foldername+"/"+filename)
Bitmap myNewImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

I hope that this will accomplish what you had in mind.

---

**UPDATE**: it seems it is indeed possible, see [Aleksandar Stojiljkovic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22063704/4848308) instead.

Comment: The problem is, that I need the files to be in resources to show in images, and also to be able to show it in WebView. So WebView needs a link to the file (including the extension). I solved it as a workaround by declaring 2 arrays in values/arrays.xml. One with the resource ids, and one with their filename extensions.

Comment: Turns out it *is* possible, Aleksandar's solution works!

Comment: Alright, I've updated my answer to direct users to his answer. Thanks for the head's up!

Answer (score 1):

This should be the best solution:

```
 TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    getResources().getValue(resourceId, value, true); 
String resname = value.string.toString().substring(13, value.string.toString().length());
```

resname = "pic.jpg"